# Programmatically Enable Wireless Display automatically in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, miracast

I Need to Enable the Wireless Display Promatically through my Application. I open the Settings screen using below Code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CAST_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I tried with Request Code as 1 (startActivityForResult(intent,1);) but this doesn't help. I didn't found any reference for the same in Docs. has anyone tried this?

Comment: are you able to find a solution for this?